# How to get lines in Netbeans that starts with echo or print_r?

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans

I know this is not programming related question so to speak, but since we are programmers and we might use Netbeans for PHP development.

I am wondering how can I get in Netbeans interface with search, macro or some other way all lines that start with `echo` or `print_r` aka as debug lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with "...get in Netbeans interface with search...".

To locate the lines, chose *Find*, tick the box *regular expression*, and enter

```
^[ \t]*(echo|print_r)
```

in the search box.